# How to Post Skills Learned at Work on Personal Website

Tags: work-experience, performance, websites

How to Post Skills Learned at Work on Personal Website.

In order to do my job, I learn things from people I work with, i.e. how to use Resource Monitor on 2012 R2 to see which computers are connecting to the server. I also learned how to analyze IIS logs for IP addresses that are continually trying to download data, and how much of it.

To simplify things, I created a script to glean through the IIS logs, output it to file, and have email program send it. This is all scheduled.

I find things like this fascinating, and would like to post this HOW-TO on a personal website (which is included in my LinkedIn profile), but somehow, my 6th sense is pushing me back (perhaps because the code is done on work computers during work hours???), so I wanted to know best approach to do this

Tell me if my approach is correct

1. Obfuscate IP addresses, and perhaps use a sample IIS log
2. As for the script I created on work computer, is it ok to email it to my personal email address? Otherwise I can simply create the entire thing from scratch at home

Is there anything else I should consider?

Thank you guys!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, nope, I haven't

Comment: If your work has a company blog, they may be willing to let you post the original version on their blog and give you credit, which you could then reference from your own website or LinkedIn.

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't publish anything related to the company without their express permission. Furthermore, you should inform about your company's policy on this kind of stuff. It can vary from company to company, but I don't think most companies will claim privacy or ownership on a script you created, without an explicit assignment.

Comment: I'll ask Management soon....

Comment: @all Management is cool with this idea, as long as it's not private, company-specific info

Answer (score 1):

Posting to your own site is a great idea because it will not only serve to display and draw more attention to your skills, but it will also provide you with a nice repository (or story) of the work you've done. This of course can be done with a simple blog.

Always be sure to get permission from the company you work for if you're going to be publishing anything you've done on the clock or on company premises.

There's no reason to disguise yourself on the web if you have permission from the company. That would be unethical and unnecessary. If possible, it would be best to secure written and signed permission to re-use and/or publish the work.

*Note that in general companies can be stingy about allowing employees to publish anything that could be found even remotely private, sensitive, or proprietary.*

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my expereience and some of other things I have seen my colleagues do on this area:

- Start a personal blog and post your experience, no need to express company-specific contextual information in your posts.
- Join Forums of topics related to your work/interests, you will learn from others and also help others solving similar problems/challenges you faced before.
- Tweet about things you stumble upon, like articles you read or blogs you regularly visit
- Create a LinkedIn profile and put links to the above

Good Luck

Comment: This is a 'how to publish', you are not addressing the OP's concerns.

Comment: @essamSALAH - I'm trying to get the hang of twitter ... posting blogs is rather time and energy intensive right now ...